# Is it possible to create a static dictionary in a C++/CLI environment?

Tags: .net, dictionary, static, c++-cli

I used in my C++/CLI project static array's like:

```
static array < array< String^>^>^ myarray=
{
  {"StringA"},
  {"StringB"}
};
```

Is it possible to create a dictionary the same way?
I was not able to create and initialize one.

```
static Dictionary< String^, String^>^ myDic=
{
  {"StringA", "1"},
  {"StringB", "2"}
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Dictionary example, and others, are called a `Collection Initializer` in C#.

You can't do it in C++/CLI.

```
// C# 3.0
class Program
{
    static Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        {1, "hello"},
        {2, "goodbye"}
    };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly at the declaration, but you could use a static constructor to do one time initialization by having your static constructor call the `Add()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about CLI but shouldn't a two dimensional array get pretty close to what you want?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  static int a[][3] = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}};
  std::cout << a[0][0] << " " << a[1][0];
  //..

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although in C++ you can't create an `std::map` and initialize it like an array, you can load the map upon construction using this constructor:

```
template <class InputIterator>
  map ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
        const Compare& comp = Compare(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

One alternative is to use an array and a search method, such as `binary_search`.  This may be useful if the data does not change.

Answer (score 0):

My approach is (.NET 4.5). This done to avoid constructor or other 'hand initializer':

```
// file.h
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
// SomeClass
public://or private:
    static Dictionary<String^, String^>^ dict = dictInitializer();
private:
    static Dictionary<String^, String^>^ dictInitializer();

// file.cpp
#include "file.h"
Dictionary<String^, String^>^ SomeClass::dictInitializer(){
    Dictionary<String^, String^>^ dict = gcnew Dictionary<String^, String^>;
    dict->Add("br","value1");
    dict->Add("cn","value2");
    dict->Add("de","value3");
    return dict;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also see [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021504/initialize-static-dictionary-while-creating-in-c-cli/42503366#42503366). In C++/CLI it is not possible to use compiler functionality like in C#, as others have written.
Therefore I created a small helper function (see the linked post), similar to the approach of @MrHIDEn here, but on his solution he seems to use fixed values.

Answer (score 0):

In C++:

```
#include <map>

std::map< int, std::string > status_to_str {
  {0, "failure"},
  {1, "none"},
  {2, "success"},
};

void print_status(int status) {
  std::cout<< status_to_str[status] << std::endl;
}
```